# Get Results QueryBuilder multiple Joins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have some little trouble getting results from QueryBuilder. Im using Symfony 2.

My problem is when i try to get data from the join. The a relation is OK, but when i try to get info from B and C and D. Well...  obviously fails.

The tables are

Users  **Many <-> Many** UsersType **Many <-> Many** CatUsersType **Many <-> Many** Applications

- Users table has the users Info
- Applications has the Applications Info
- CatUsersType has the Type of Users for each Application
- UsersType has the id of User and UserType

This is my code:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$users  = $qb->select('a, b, c, d')
    ->from('MyBundle:users', 'a')
    ->innerJoin('MyBundle:userstype','b', 'WITH', 'b.iduser = a.id')
    ->innerJoin('MyBundle:catuserstype','c','WITH', 'c.id = b.idusertype')
    ->innerJoin('MyBundle:applications','d', 'WITH', 'd.id = c.idapp')
    ->where('d.id = :app_id')
    ->setParameter('app_id', $idapp)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
if (count($users) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    $elements = array('data' => array());
    foreach ($users as $usr) {
        $created = $usr->getCreated();//['date'];
        if($created instanceof \DateTime){
            $created = $created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        $tmp = [
            'username' => $usr->getUsername(),
            'name' => $usr->getName() . ' ' .$usr->getLastname(),
            'created'=> $created,
            'myField'=> $usr->getIdusertype(),    //Problems here
            'myApp' => $usr->getIdapp(),         //And here idApp comes from c or d tables
            'id' => $usr->getId()
        ];
        array_push($elements['data'], $tmp);
        $i++;
    }
    $response = $elements;
}
```

**Edit:**

I got the same result changing the innerJoin to leftJoin or rightJoin

Attempted to call method "getIdusertype" on class users when the method is from the Class userstype

I found the problem.
The relations are wrong. I would correct the code and share the correct code. Thanks to all

Comment: Change innerJoin to leftJoin and see if that helps.  We can then refine things just a bit.

Comment: The same results. Attempted to call method "getIdusertype" on class users when the method is from the Class userstype

Comment: I am guessing you have relation issues and are possibly confusing id's with objects.  Just use find to query a single user without joins.  Then make sure that $user->getIdusertype() actually returns a UsersType object.

Comment: Maybe i try with only one join and have the same results. The instruction foreach ($users as $usr)  returns a different type of class for each $usr, when i have only 1 user. 1 class type for each join. ¡¿?!

Comment: I strongly suspect you are not using ManyToMany properly.  You never need to worry about the id's when using Doctrine 2.  Please update your question with the mapping code for Users.  Might also want to look at some ManyToMany examples and get one working first.  Remember that with a ManyToMany relation, each user can have multiple types so it makes no sense to ask the user for just one.  It's possible you want a OneToOne relation.

Comment: @Cerad You are correct. All relationships are wrong constructed. Thank you very much :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access properties of `usertype` and `catuserstype` directly from your user object. And a second problem is, that your current code would only work for many-to-one relations, but not for many-to-many relation. If you would have distinct relations, the code could be

```
foreach ($users as $usr) {
    $created = $usr->getCreated();//['date'];
    if($created instanceof \DateTime){
        $created = $created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    $tmp = [
        'username' => $usr->getUsername(),
        'name' => $usr->getName() . ' ' .$usr->getLastname(),
        'created'=> $created,
        'myField'=> $usr->getUsertype()->getIdusertype(),
        'myApp' => $usr->getUsertype()->getCatuserstype()->getIdapp(),
        'id' => $usr->getId()
    ];
    array_push($elements['data'], $tmp);
    $i++;
}
```

but with many-to-many its more like

```
foreach ($users as $usr) {
    $created = $usr->getCreated();//['date'];
    if($created instanceof \DateTime){
        $created = $created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    foreach ($usr->getUsertype as $usertype) {
        foreach ($usertype->getCatuserstype() as $catuserstype) {
            $tmp = [
                'username' => $usr->getUsername(),
                'name'     => $usr->getName() . ' ' .$usr->getLastname(),
                'created'  => $created,
                'myField'  => $usertype->getIdusertype(),
                'myApp'    => $catuserstype->getIdapp(),
                'id'       => $usr->getId()
            ];
        }
    }
    array_push($elements['data'], $tmp);
    $i++;
}
```

or some other way of combining your `$elements['data']` array.

**Edit:**

I assumed in my answer that there are proper relations set for entities. So you would be able to write your query like

```
$users  = $qb->select('a')
    ->from('MyBundle:users', 'a')
    ->innerJoin('a.userstype', 'b')
    ->innerJoin('b.catuserstype', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.applications', 'd')
    ->where('d.id = :app_id')
    ->setParameter('app_id', $idapp)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```